# NodeJS and supertest : start tests with npm command

Tags: node.js, testing, command, npm, supertest

I use [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest). I want to launch all tests in tests directory.
My /tests/tests.js file :

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('express.io')();

//add good url with http:// and redirection 
request(app)
  .post('/add/')
  .expect(201)
  .send({url: 'http://www.google.fr'})
  .end(function(err, res){
      console.log(res.body.url);
    if (err) throw err;
    request(app)
        .get('/redirect/' + res.body.url.generatedid)
        .expect(302)
        .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
         });
});

//add good url with www. and redirection  
request(app)
  .post('/add/')
  .expect(201)
  .send({url: 'www.google.com'})
  .end(function(err, res){
    if (err) throw err;
       request(app)
        .get('/redirect/' + res.body.url.generatedid)
        .expect(302)
        .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
         });
    });
```

I want to launch with the npm command : npm run tests.
I changed my package.json file.

```
    {
  "name": "UrlShortener",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Licence pro Web JS project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "release" : "npm install",
    "tests" : "supertest tests/*.js",
    "dev" : "DEBUG=feedback supervisor index"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express.io": "^1.1.13",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.21",
    "nunjucks": "^1.1.0",
    "short-id": "0.1.0-1",
    "socket.io": "^1.2.1",
    "validator": "^3.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "supertest": "^0.15.0"
 },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  }
}
```

npm run start works but when I try npm run tests I have :

```
> UrlShortener@0.0.1 tests c:\Users\Damien\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\urlshortener
> supertest tests/*.js

'supertest' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

npm ERR! UrlShortener@0.0.1 tests: `supertest tests/*.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the UrlShortener@0.0.1 tests script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the UrlShortener package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     supertest tests/*.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls UrlShortener
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "d:\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "d:\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\np
-cli.js" "run" "tests"
npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\Damien\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\urlshortener
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\Users\Damien\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\urlshortener\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to launch my tests (supertest) with npm command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`supertest` package doesn't contain an executable script. Replace your `scripts.tests` in `package.json` to this:

```
"scripts": {
  "tests" : "node tests/tests.js"
}
```

You can specify which test files should be run in `tests.js` by requiring them.